# jq to get count of a element in a string and make it to a dict list

Tags: jq

question 1) I want to count all dict in this string, the result should be `3` for the sample input below.

question 2) I want want to count name == foo, the result should be `2`

question 3) I want to get `{"foo":["b","c"],"go":["d"]}`

Sample input:

```json
{
  "name": "foo",
  "title": "b"
}
{
  "name": "foo",
  "title": "c"
}
{
  "name": "go",
  "title": "d"
}
```

Comment: What did you try and how did your efforts fail in the process?

Comment: I don't know how to cover it to a list of dict with jq. it will be easy if it can be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a stream of objects. You will need to group all those document into one to work on them collectively.

There are two ways to achieve this:

- Using "slurp mode" (`--slurp`/`-s`)
- Using `[ inputs ]`, which requires `-null-input`/`-n`.

---

The number of documents in the stream:

```sh
jq -sr length
```

```sh
jq -nr '[ inputs ] | length'
```

---

The number of documents whose root object have value `foo` for key `name`:

```sh
jq -sr 'map( select( .name == "foo" ) ) | length'
```

```sh
jq -nr '[ inputs | select( .name == "foo" ) ] | length'
```

---

The titles grouped by name:

```sh
jq -s 'reduce .[] as $doc ( {}; .[ $doc.name ] += [ $doc.title ] )'
```

```sh
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $doc ( {}; .[ $doc.name ] += [ $doc.title ] )'
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid slurping and any other method of creating an array in order to take its length, you can use the following stream-oriented counting function:

```
def count(s): reduce s as $x (0; .+1);
```

For example, instead of:

```
jq -nr '[ inputs ] | length'
```

you could write:

```
jq -n -f count.jq
```

where count.jq contains:

```
def count(s): reduce s as $x (0; .+1);
count(inputs)
```

Similarly, instead of

```
 jq -nr '[ inputs | select( .name == "foo" ) ] | length'
```

you would use the same "def" with:

```
count(inputs | select( .name == "foo" ))
```